# jquery ocr only inside of a div

Tags: jquery, ocr

I was thinking of using OCR barcode scanner in my next application but I am not pretty sure how to start. My idea is to scan barcode located only inside draggable and resizeable div located in middle of a screen. I know the way **how to scan barcode** and **how to make resizeable div** but, ***how to scan barcode only inside it?***

example picture (photomath): http://www.e-zone.com.hk/thumbs/735x420/1/channelnews/20150521180741.jpg